# De-queue and linked list

Tags: linked-list, queue

I want to know what a de-queue is? 
Is it same as a linked list?
If yes then,

Is it something like "de-queue can be represented as a linked list" ?
or
Is de-queue a "singly linked list" or "double linked list" (like alias to anyone of them)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**de-queue** is **Double-ended queue**. In **queue** you have two basic operations:

```
1. Add element at the end of queue
2. Remove element from start of the queue.
```

**de-queue** supports total four basic operations:

```
1. Add element at start.
2. Remove element from start.
3. Add element at end.
4. Remove element from end.
```

Of course you can add other functionality like getting the value of first or last element without removing it etc.
You can implement **de-queue** using any data structure but efficient implementations are done using [dyanmic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) or [doubly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list). For more details follow this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue